# How to work with Action Link when using CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<li class="rtsLI" id="Summary"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:rtsXXX.OnClientTabSelected(this‌​, 0);" class="rtsLink"><span class="rtsTxt">Test</span></a></li>
```

Above I am replacing with following actionlink:

```
<li class="rtsLI" >@Html.ActionLink("test1", "Index", new { Area = "Area1", Controller = "controller1" }, new { @class = "rtsLink rtsTxt"})</li> "
```

At first css is working fine. But when using Actionlink, css not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option will be to use `@Url.Action` extension method

```
<li class="rtsLI" id="Summary"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity" })" class="rtsLink"><span class="rtsTxt">User Security</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard ActionLink helper always HTML encodes the link text. This means that you cannot use it if you want to render HTML inside. You have 3 possibilities:

1. Modify your CSS so that you don't need a span inside the link and so that the `rtsTxt` class could directly be applied to the link
2. Write a custom ActionLink helper that doesn't HTML encode the text and which would allow you to generate the same markup:

   ```
   public static class ActionLinkExtensions
   {
       public static IHtmlString ActionLinkUnencoded(
           this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
           string linkText, 
           string actionName, 
           object routeValues, 
           object htmlAttributes
       )
       {
           var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
           var link = new TagBuilder("a");
           link.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
           link.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(actionName, routeValues);
           link.InnerHtml = linkText;
           return new HtmlString(link.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```

   and then:

   ```
   <li>
       @Html.ActionLinkUnencoded(
           "<span class=\"rtsTxt\">User Security</span>", 
           "index", 
           new { area = "Tools", controller = "UserSecurity" }, 
           new { @class = "rtsLink" }
       )
   </li>
   ```
3. Use the Url.Action helper:

   ```
   <li class="rtsLI">
       <a href="@Url.Action("index", new { area = "Tools", controller = "UserSecurity" })" class="rtsLink">
           <span class="rtsTxt">User Security</span>
       </a>
   </li>
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works fine with CSS. How to use the above onclick event in Action method.

Comment: You could include it in the htmlAttributes: `new { @class = "rtsLink", onclick = "javascript:rtsMemoTextMenuContainerTabsManager.OnClientTabSelected(this‌​, 0);" }`.

Comment: i used like this. Is this correct or I need to do any change. <a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity"})" "javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:rtsMemoTextMenuContainerTabsManager.OnClientTabSelected(this, 0);" class="rtsLink">
        <span class="rtsTxt">User Security</span>
    </a>

Comment: Seems fine. It's just that in your initial link the `href` was empty.

Comment: What change I need to do for the 'href' being empty. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use any helper in this case. The whole purpose of url helpers is to generate non-empty urls pointing to controller actions. If you want empty href then your initial code seems fine.

Comment: Initial code means that I posted in the 3rd comment.AM I correct. Thanks.

Comment: This code will generate an href pointing to the controller action indicated by the url helper. It is OK if this is what you need. If you need `href="javascript:void(0);"` as shown in your question then simply don't use any helper at all.

Comment: new { @class = "rtsLink", onclick = "javascript:rtsMemoTextMenuContainerTabsManager.OnClientTabSelected(this‌​, 0);"} How to put the above code inside the following code. <li class="rtsLI" id="Summary">
    <a href= "@Url.Action("Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity" })" class="rtsLink">
        <span class="rtsTxt">User Security</span>
    </a>
</li> My problem is that custom image using css is displaying and hidden atlast(I can see the image in the list using alert()). SO I need to properly use this code. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You simply add the `onclick` to the `<a>` tag, the same way you did with the `class` attribute.

Comment: I used in the way as you said, but the custom image in the list menu is not persists. That is, I had used alert msg to see the image. Image is displaying and afterwards, it is hidden. I think, again the page is loaded and I am not able to see the image. Thanks.

Comment: That's because I suppose that when you click on the link, since your href is now pointing to the controller action, the browser is immediately redirected away to this controller action leaving it no time for the javascript that you have placed in the onclick to ever execute.

Answer (score 0):

Write code this way:

```
<li class="rtsLI" >@Html.ActionLink("<span class='rtsTxt'>User Security</span>", "Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity" }, new { @class = "rtsLink"})</li>`
```

Comment: This one should create almost the same html as presented. Try to add  id="Summary" for li node that wrapping @Html.ActionLink

Comment: displaying as "<span class='rtsTxt'>User Security</span>" instead of "User Security" without any css.

Comment: Use variant with Url.Action this is the best option