# How to replace the lists with mvc4 actionlink lists

Tags: asp.net, html, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Working Fine:

```
<li class="rtsLI" id="Summary">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"            
       onclick="javascript:rtsTestContainerTabsManager.OnClientTabSelected(this, 0);" 
       class="rtsLink">
           <span class="rtsTxt">Test</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Want to replace the above code with Actionlink: (**CSS is not working here**..)

```
<li class="rtsLI" >
    @Html.ActionLink("Controller1", "Index", 
                     new { Area = "Area1", Controller = "Controller1" }, 
                     new { @class = "rtsLink rtsTxt" })
</li>
```

My problem is that **CSS** is not **recognised** when I am using **Actionlink**. I used single css attribute. Then also it is not working.

Please provide me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean on "CSS is not recognised"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to work with Action Link when using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210193/how-to-work-with-action-link-when-using-css)

Comment: What's the html output of the ActionLink and compare that to your html example

Comment: @nemesv, CSS is not recognised means "CSS is not recognised"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to wrap  tags within the anchor tag, as far as I know this will not work with `@Html.ActionLink()`. For axample, if you try doing this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("<span class='rtsTxt'>User Security</span>", "Index", 
                 new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity" }, 
                 new { @class = "rtsLink" })
```

will not work.

Use Url.Action helper method as a workaround instead (in case no other answers better fit your needs).

For example, the following can be marked up in your view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index",  
                 new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity" })" class="rtsLink" onclick="javascript:rtsMemoTextMenuContainerTabsManager.OnClientTabSelected(this, 0);">
   <span class="rtsTxt">User Security</span>
</a>
```

Comment: url.Action accepts only (str,str,obj,str) and you are having (str,str,obj,obj)